# rake aborted! undefined method `setup' for ActiveAdmin:Module

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have installed active admin on my development machine and it works fine.
But when i run `heroku run rake db:migrate` it gives me following error

```
rake aborted! undefined method `setup' for ActiveAdmin:Module
```

here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

gem 'pg'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'sorcery'#, "~> 0.7.12"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'localeapp'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem "activeadmin", :git => "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"
  gem 'sass-rails'#,   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails'#, '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue as I am getting same issue?

Comment: not yet, sorry , vote up the question, so we could get the answer @ManishShrivastava

Comment: but i think its related to gem "active_admin" github path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  gem "activeadmin", :git => "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"
```

Don't declare active admin under any group.
Atleast it wont work in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I wanted to try activeadmin-cms 0.1.0 and I had the same problem.

The gem activeadmin-cms is not compatible with activeadmin 0.6.0 (I have not tested other version of activeadmin)